# Trigger Paste Action when pasting text into TextArea MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, overriding, paste

This is more of a general design question that I am currently looking into in order to incorporate it to an application and need some insight/ ideas on how to go about this.

Basically I have an MVC application. In one of my views I have a TextArea and some radio buttons that define a specific operation I want to perform.
What I want to achieve is that when one of these radio buttons is selected and the user pastes some text into this TextArea, I want it to trigger some functionality that operates on the text that is being pasted into this TextArea (as soon as the text is pasted).
I've looked at event handling but this doesn't seem to be useful since this application follows the MVC architecture so I know there should be a different/better way to go about this (ie perhaps creating a new controller, just don't know where to begin).

Any pointers or links to other sites that accomplish this would be useful :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a javascript/jquery event handler for when the text changes, and fire an appropriate callback (AJAX) back to a controller to perform the action.

```
$('#textBoxId').change(function (e) {

    //Perform AJAX callback to controller
});
```